# How to get magento 2 custom address entity id

Tags: magento2.2.3

How to get  entity_id of created custom address after executing of `customer_address_save_after` event

```
  private function getEntityId($observer)
  {
        $customerAddress = $observer->getCustomerAddress();
        $entityId = $customerAddress->getCustomer()->getEntityId();
        return $entityId; //entity_id of the customer_entity table
  }
```

This method returns the  entity_id of the `customer_entity` table, but I need the `entity_id` of the `customer_address_entity` table

Answer (score 1):

You can get the address id as given below.

```
$customerAddress = $observer->getCustomerAddress();
$addressId = $customerAddress->getId();
```

Comment: not working  for me

Comment: May be you are getting the wrong address object. Try to print the address data by `$customerAddress->getData()` and check.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$event = $observer->getEvent();
$customer = $event->getCustomer();
$addresses = $customer->getAddresses(); //array
```